# Join same table with results on one row

Tags: sql

I am trying to join multiple tables and need to return matching information on the same row.

I have 3 possible prices

1. Standard (default) pricing
2. Website specific pricing
3. Customer (of website) specific pricing

These are "*tiered*" pricing so I need to deal with the quantities.

The tables may have records that don't match.  For instance Standard Pricing may have Quantity 1, 100, 200, 500 pricing while Website pricing may only have Quantity 1 and 25 pricing and customer pricing may have quantity 1, 100, 200 and that is all.

So pricing table looks like:

```
PriceID, Quantity, Price, WebsiteID, CustomerGroupID
10       1         10     NULL       NULL
11       1         9      1          NULL
12       1         8      1          5
13       10        9      NULL       NULL
14       20        8      NULL       NULL
15       8         7      1          5
```

What I would like to see is:

```
Quantity, sPrice, wPrice, cPrice
1         10      9       8
8         NULL    NULL    7
10        9       NULL    NULL
20        8       NULL    NULL
```

Once i have that I can use CASE statements to deal with which price and other functions on the pricing - but I can't seem to figure out the method to bring them together like this.

Comment: It's not clear, at least not for me. I only see one table. What have you tried?

Comment: Is Price ID the shared id between the tables?  Or is it Website ID & Customer Group ID

Comment: It's all the same table I am just trying to query the single table and bring the data together onto single lines.

Comment: @PaulGiesenhagen: _"The tables may have records"_ Also, how do you want to join this table with itself?

Comment: How do you know what is sPrice or wPrice or cPrice?  Is that a separate table based off PriceID?

Comment: The priceID is not needed - sorry if it confused.  Ultimately each record is a snapshot of the price for either standard pricing, website pricing or customer pricing (to help clear more - their are many websites - but in these cases I am really just dealing with them one at a time).  But it matters because a website may not have any defined price or customer defined price which then falls back to standard pricing... does that help?

Comment: sPrice, wPrice and cPrice are just renamed price columns from the same table

Comment: @TimSchmelter  Sorry "table"  the table is called sd_ObjectPrice and it holds all the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should meet your need:

```
select
    quantity,
    sum(case when websiteid is null and customergroupid is null
         then price
         end) as sprice,
    sum(case when websiteid is not null and customergroupid is null
        then price
        end) as wprice,
    sum(case when customergroupid is not null
        then price
        end) as cprice
from
  t
group by
  quantity
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20b43/1)

Comment: Looks like it may - but the sum has me a bit stumped - why is that needed ... thank you

Comment: ok this solution won't work as I need to do some case statements and calculations based on other joins -  Example after quantity, I need to do something similar to CASE WHEN sPrice IS NULL THEN cPrice ELSE sPrice END